# Xamarin.Forms transfer data between screens with MVVM

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms

I have two screens.

The 1st one have two `Entries` and Save button, the 2nd one - two `Labels`.

Both have corresponding binded `ViewModels`.

e.g. 1st `XAML`:

```
<Entry x:Name="Entry1" Text="{Binding Entry1}"/>
<Button Command="{Binding SaveCommand}" Text="Save"/>
```

1st ViewModel:

```
class Screen1ViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };

    private string entry1;
    public string Entry1;
    {
        get { return entry1; }
        set
        {
            entry1= value;
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Entry1"));
        }
    }
    //similar code for Entry2

    public ICommand SaveCommand { protected set; get; }

    public Screen1ViewModel()
    {
        SaveCommand = new Command(OnSubmit);
    }

    public void OnSubmit()
    {
        //I guess here I supposed to transfer data from 1st screen to 2nd
    }

}
```

Is there any easy way to get strings from 1st screen entries and pass them to 2nd screen labels using ViewModels?

Comment: What MVVM framework are u using?

Comment: @Alex please take a look at my updated answer, I added explanation to my code, hope it will help you.

Answer (score 1):

I've implemented very simplified sample for you.
Of course it's not the best implementation to do the following:

```
((testApp.App)App.Current).MainPage.Navigation
```

The best way to implement navigation is to have navigation service like in the following article:
https://mallibone.com/post/a-simple-navigation-service-for-xamarinforms

It's better since in this case your viewModel does not know anything about pages, it knows only string page key. It's also easier to understand code and debug it, since there is a central calling point.

There is also MVVM light toolkit available. The following article demonstrates how to leverage its features and to implement navigation:
https://mobileprogrammerblog.wordpress.com/2017/01/21/xamarin-forms-with-mvvm-light/

Messaging service is the worst thing I can recommend regarding navigation since it's hard to understand code and debugging is a real mess. By decoupling code you make dependent things independent and new people can't get a head or tail of it how the code works. Messaging is good when you pass events from inner viewModels to the root page view model or from view model to view or to page, but it does not suit for navigation task.

My simple sample can be found below:
App code:

```
public App()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   MainPage = new NavigationPage(new Views.Page1());
}
```

Page1.xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage 
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
    x:Class="testApp.Views.Page1"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:testApp.Views;assemply=testApp">
    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <local:Page1ViewModel/>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout>
        <Entry Text="{Binding TextPropertyValue}" />
        <Button Command="{Binding SaveCommand}" Text="Save"/>
            </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Page1ViewModel:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace testApp.Views
{
    public class Page1ViewModel:INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public Page1ViewModel()
        {
            SaveCommand = new Xamarin.Forms.Command(HandleAction);

        }

        async void HandleAction(object obj)
        {
            await ((testApp.App)App.Current).MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(
            new Page2()
            {
                BindingContext = new Page2ViewModel(TextPropertyValue)
            }); 

        }
        string entry1;
        public string TextPropertyValue
        {
            get
            {
                return entry1;
            }
            set
            {
                if (value!=entry1)
                {
                    entry1 = value;
                    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(TextPropertyValue)));
                }
            }
        }


        public ICommand SaveCommand
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }
}
```

Page2.xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" x:Class="testApp.Views.Page2">
    <ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout>
        <Label Text="{Binding EntryValue}"/>
            </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
```

Page2.xaml.cs

```
public partial class Page2 : ContentPage
{
    public Page2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Page2ViewModel

```
using System;
namespace testApp.Views
{
    public class Page2ViewModel
    {
        public Page2ViewModel(string entry)
        {
            EntryValue = entry;
        }

        public string EntryValue
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want these View Models to be coupled or have relationships with each other, you would want some sort of event aggregator or messaging (pub-sub) mechanism. Xamarin Forms comes with a Messaging service out of the box called the [Messaging Center](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/messaging-center) to accomplish this.